# Count and print the number of words in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

I am trying to write a program that count and print the number of words in a file. The problem is that I can't use functions like split() or partition() as we don't cover them yet.

```
def CountWords(TextfileName)
    for
```

I don't know how to start my program, can anyone explain for me a little more about reading text file?

The program should look like this:

Suppose the file some.txt contains the following:

```
Words make up other words. This is a line.
Sequences of words make sentences.
I like words but I don’t like MS Word.
There’s another word for how I feel about MSWord: @#%&
```

Then the program run produces the result shown below.

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
$ python3 findWord.py
Enter filename: some.txt
33 words
```

Comment: Looks like some homework assignment. Please share what you have written till now!

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('some.txt') as f:
   count = len(f.read().split())
print(count)
```